# Unable to locate adb from AVD Manager (Nexus 6p api 28)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[Android Studio gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeHJ5.png)

In don't know what going on in did the installation and downloading of all the sdk, android studio, flutter sdk and dart multiples times but stuck in this error. Did a lot of research on this see multiple YouTube videos' but still cant get rid of it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. Did you install `adb`? Is it in the `$PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the `flutter doctor -v` details to see where you stuck